# Multivariate Distribution Modeling

Tags: probability

I am currently trying to model the joint-distribution of bi-variate data for two rv's, X and Y. These two random variables looking at them independently seem to take the shape of a exponential or generalized pareto distribution (type 1) (as confirmed by looking at individual PDF/CDF fits). The rvs represent the amount of time between observing two recurring events. My question is, how would one go about modeling the bivariate distribution?
I was thinking of using a gaussian mixture model, since it can represent any function in multi-dimensional space, but are there more suitable distributions given they have pareto like shapes?

Comment: Take a look at copulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).  You can have a bivariate distribution where the marginals are Pareto distributions.

Comment: yeah copula probably is the best way to go, if you're looking for joint distributions... thank you I will try that